# Bootstrap 3 - Menu Issues (Highlight and Hide)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with my bootstrap 3 dropdown menu, specifically when its on the hamburger version of the menu. The following actions are happening:

- Once a menu item is selected, all items in the ul remain highlighted, the next time you open the menu.
- When the page is viewed on a mobile device, the menu doesnt disappear once a menu item is selected.

I have tried a couple of different scripts, similar to [this Github topic](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12852) but I thinks I am placing the script in the wrong place. I have made a few different changes to try get it to work but I cant figure it out. I have taken the source from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) topic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the navbar code I am using:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="myNavBar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a href="#Home">
        <img src="images/home.png" alt="Logo" width="275" height="50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#comp1.1">Section 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp1.2">Section 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp1.3">Section 1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#comp2.1">Section 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp2.2">Section 2.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem. https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/BxKvMQ

Comment: @DhavalJardosh thanks Dhaval, the menu that pops up i.e. section 1 & section 2 after first click of hamburger menu, I want that to disappear after a menu item is selected.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Had to add some `jQuery` to it, and it worked.

Will make slideUp transition smoother as soon as I get the chance. 
Just adding and removing few classed worked.

> And on toggle, you get the removed classes back. So not to worry about that.

Place the below code in your html before your `<html>`

```
<script>
 JqUery  text
</script>
```

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("in");
  $(".navbar-toggle").addClass("collapsed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="myNavBar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a href="#Home">
        <img src="images/home.png" alt="Logo" width="275" height="50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#comp1.1">Section 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp1.2">Section 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp1.3">Section 1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#comp2.1">Section 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#comp2.2">Section 2.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: looks great Dhaval, thanks. Now where and how do I add that to my index.html file. Sorry for the stupid question, this is all new to me.